# Adding param with value to array

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have this code:

```
    $campaignUserModel = new CampaignUserModel();
    $subcontractors = $campaignUserModel
        ->select('campaigns_users.*, users.fullname user_fullname')
        ->join('users', 'users.id = campaigns_users.user_id')
        ->where('campaign_id', $id)
        ->findAll();

    $postModel = new PostModel();
    foreach ($subcontractors as $subcontractor) {
        $subcontractor_posts = $postModel
            ->where('user_id', $subcontractor['id'])
            ->where('campaign_id', $id)
            ->countAllResults();

        $subcontractor['posts_count'] = $subcontractor_posts;

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($subcontractor);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($subcontractors);
    echo "</pre>";
```

In first var_dump() I see:

> array(7) {   ["id"]=>   string(1) "3"   ["campaign_id"]=>   string(1)
> "1"   ["user_id"]=>   string(1) "3"   ["quantity"]=>   string(1) "2"
> ["status"]=>   string(1) "2"   ["user_fullname"]=>   string(17) "Edek
> Podwykonawca"   ["posts_count"]=>   int(1) }

so **posts_count** is added. But when foreach finished and I display second var_dump() with array of all subcontractor i can't see **posts_count**.

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `$subcontractor` variable *by reference*:

I.e:

Instead of:❌

```php
// ...
 foreach ($subcontractors as $subcontractor) {
// ...
```

Use this:✅

```php
// ...
 foreach ($subcontractors as &$subcontractor) {
// ...
```

*Notice the **ampersand** (`&`) infront of `$subcontractor`*

Resource: [References Explained](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)